# How to GET JSON with String Parameters and header with Python Requests?

Tags: python, json, get

I am trying to do some scraping from websites using GET and POST methods, but now I am facing a new challenge.

I am trying to get data from a credit simulator, I found this portuguese site (https://www.eurobic.pt/credito/credito-pessoal-standard).

As far as I know, I need to use GET method, but I have to specify the data (the Loan amount, the months duration...). I usually do it by creating a dictionary structure but that is not working.

Here is my code:

`code`

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.eurobic.pt/api/SiteCore/Simulators/GetSimulation?UniqueReference=0&RefDate=2022-3-15&doCalculateDuration=false&LoanDurationMonths=41&LoanInstallment=71.21&LoanAmount=2500.00&AquisitionCost=0.00&IsSimpleSimulation=true&ProductId=OUTRAS&doReturnInstallments=false&CalculationMode=STD&Type=pessoal&isDefaultCall=false' 

headers = {'authority': 'www.eurobic.pt',
'method': 'GET',
'path': '/api/SiteCore/Simulators/GetSimulation?UniqueReference=0&RefDate=2022-3-15&doCalculateDuration=false&LoanDurationMonths=41&LoanInstallment=71.21&LoanAmount=2500.00&AquisitionCost=0.00&IsSimpleSimulation=true&ProductId=OUTRAS&doReturnInstallments=false&CalculationMode=STD&Type=pessoal&isDefaultCall=false',
'scheme':'https',
'accept': '*/*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
'cookie': 'incap_ses_1297_1257437=rqCMepfwwQHcpxkGE9//Ed9dL2IAAAAAIF+bxa7cvugSlSI3dMdYSQ==; ASP.NET_SessionId=mxkgte5ls3s4l5kgat33exbd; visid_incap_1257437=F/jcLYoRTh2VqwSqtukmu99dL2IAAAAAQkIPAAAAAACAO+yiAaXhXOj+3qzLKuNnnni0rUgBqpTE; _ga=GA1.2.557667603.1647271440; _gid=GA1.2.111244898.1647271440; visid_incap_1952501=aytz0fZsQN6E61LvSU1LoEBeL2IAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAtVqyz/zax0cktiweYvQ7f; incap_ses_1213_1952501=0LdkB29/4kvAjw6ApXHVEEBeL2IAAAAAOpApAHE2dqcGJ70NQCf6Jg==; RT=s=1647271515225&r=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.eurobic.pt%2FSimuladorpessoal%2Favancado.aspx%3FUniqueReference%3DJFLDOOWO69; _gat_gtag_UA_102753073_1=1',
'referer': 'https://www.eurobic.pt/credito/super-credito-pessoal',
'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

        
data= {'UniqueReference': 0,
'RefDate': '2022-3-15',
'doCalculateDuration': 'false',
'LoanDurationMonths': 41,
'LoanInstallment': 71.21,
'LoanAmount': 2500.00,
'AquisitionCost': 0.00,
'IsSimpleSimulation': 'true',
'ProductId': 'OUTRAS',
'doReturnInstallments': 'false',
'CalculationMode':'STD',
'Type': 'pessoal',
'isDefaultCall': 'false'}

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,params=data, verify=False).json()
```

I am getting a 200 response, so I am being able to enter the url. The problem is to get the json. It gives me an error : **raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value**

The goal is to get the TAN or TAEG that change when duration months("Prazo") or loan amount("Montante") values change.

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: First: have you tried to set "content-type": "application/json" in the header?
Second: Seems like the response returns None. Please check  requests.get(url,headers=headers,params=data, verify=False).text

Comment: Still not working. The ".text" does not give the information that i want to retrieve. I am trying to see the TAN or TAEG values according to the specific loan amount and duration.

Comment: But text provides information? text is the "none json parsed" response. It seems that  they simply not send a json as a response, if text is not none

Comment: The text is not retrieving the correct data that I pretend.

Comment: do you get json back if you load `url` in a browser?  the problem seems to be that the site doesn't return the content you expect, rather than your code. also, you probably need to include the `path` in the `url` if it's not already

Comment: You should try to use response.json() returns which is a  JSON response in Python dictionary format as in [this link](https://pynative.com/parse-json-response-using-python-requests-library/)

Comment: I have tried, but I always receive the same error : raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None JSONDecodeError: Expecting value